# tdd tests not running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tdd

the tests itself do not run and here what the error message shows me
[the tests itself do not run and here what the error message shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9dXA.png)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.<init>(JUnit5TestLoader.java:34)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:124)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:346)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:604)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:371)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 13 more

this is the test i'm trying to run

```
    @Test
public void testAddition() {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    double result = calculator.solve("12 20 +");
    double expected = 32;
    assertEquals(result, expected, 0.00001);
    
    result = calculator.solve("100 200 +");
    expected = 300;
    assertEquals(result, expected, 0.00001);
}
```

}

Comment: What did you add as a dependency to your project? What does your test look like? Do you have only tests using junit5 (jupiter)? Or do you have also a junit4 tests?

Comment: i have only junit 5 tests

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your test runner did not found the test.

1. Find you what your test runner is: (eg. junit4 or junit5, started via Eclipse, IntelliJ, or via command line and maven(pom.xml) or gradle ?
2. Find out what are the default file-path and filename-pattern the test runner considers.

For example: in most java projects you should have your tests in "projectroot/src/test/java//MyClassTest.java"
and all Tests should end in "*Test.java"

But when the pom.xml defines other path/filename pattern then the default pattern for the  maven-surefire-plugin in the  section , you might need change you path and/or test-file-names.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>**/*Test.java</includes>
      <argLine>-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=nl -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT ${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
<!-->....<--!>
```

if you are using maven: try "mvn test" and look after the line

```
"[INFO] ---  maven-surefire-plugin:x.xx.x:test"
```

If there are any tests found.